# getting error - java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: android, arrays, string, listview

I have written some code to set data to `listview` from a webpage. I have read the webpage successfully and stored necessary data in `String` array. Now i want to assign that to `ListView` using `ArrayAdapter` but the data is not getting set in `listview`. Please help me solve the error:

**FULL LOG CAT**

```
11-07 23:41:40.150: E/AndroidRuntime(3400): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-07 23:41:40.150: E/AndroidRuntime(3400): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
11-07 23:41:40.150: E/AndroidRuntime(3400):     at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:411)
11-07 23:41:40.150: E/AndroidRuntime(3400):     at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:432)
11-07 23:41:40.150: E/AndroidRuntime(3400):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.add(ArrayAdapter.java:178)
11-07 23:41:40.150: E/AndroidRuntime(3400):     at com.air.test.Smscollection$sendMessageAsync.onPostExecute(Smscollection.java:91)
11-07 23:41:40.150: E/AndroidRuntime(3400):     at com.air.test.Smscollection$sendMessageAsync.onPostExecute(Smscollection.java:1)
11-07 23:41:40.150: E/AndroidRuntime(3400):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
11-07 23:41:40.150: E/AndroidRuntime(3400):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
11-07 23:41:40.150: E/AndroidRuntime(3400):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
11-07 23:41:40.150: E/AndroidRuntime(3400):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-07 23:41:40.150: E/AndroidRuntime(3400):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
11-07 23:41:40.150: E/AndroidRuntime(3400):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-07 23:41:40.150: E/AndroidRuntime(3400):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-07 23:41:40.150: E/AndroidRuntime(3400):     at  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-07 23:41:40.150: E/AndroidRuntime(3400):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-07 23:41:40.150: E/AndroidRuntime(3400):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-07 23:41:40.150: E/AndroidRuntime(3400):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Output of logcat so as to verify that data is being stored in `String array`

```
11-07 23:03:47.640: I/NEW VAUES(3192): Happiness is Like a Butterfly, You run after it, It keeps flying away. But if you stand still, It comes and Sits On You Wish you lots of Butterflies
11-07 23:03:47.640: I/NEW VAUES(3192): Happiness is Like a Butterfly, You run after it, It keeps flying away. But if you stand still, It comes and Sits On You Wish you lots of Butterfly
11-07 23:03:47.640: I/NEW VAUES(3192): Happiness is Like a Butterfly, You run after it, It keeps flying away. But if you stand still, It comes and Sits On You Wish you lots of Butterfies
11-07 23:03:47.640: I/NEW VAUES(3192): Happiness is Like a Butterfly, You run after it, It keeps flying away. But if you stand still, It comes and Sits On You Wish you lots of Butterfly
11-07 23:03:47.640: I/NEW VAUES(3192): Happiness is Like a Butterfly, You run after it, It keeps flying away. But if you stand still, It comes and Sits On You Wish you lots of Butterflies
11-07 23:03:47.640: I/VALUES(3192): Happiness is Like a Butterfly, You run after it, It keeps flying away. But if you stand still, It comes and Sits On You Wish you lots of Butterflies<br/>Happiness is Like a Butterfly, You run after it, It keeps flying away. But if you stand still, It comes and Sits On You Wish you lots of Butterfly<br/>Happiness is Like a Butterfly, You run after it, It keeps flying away. But if you stand still, It comes and Sits On You Wish you lots of Butterfies<br/>Happiness is Like a Butterfly, You run after it, It keeps flying away. But if you stand still, It comes and Sits On You Wish you lots of Butterfly<br/>Happiness is Like a Butterfly, You run after it, It keeps flying away. But if you stand still, It comes and Sits On You Wish you lots of Butterflies
```

**CODE**

```
public class Smscollection extends Activity {

private Spinner spinner1;
private ProgressDialog pd;
private StringBuilder response;
private ListView listView;
private String[] values = new String[0];
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_smscollection);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerCategory);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> av, View view, int id,
                long ids) {
            new sendMessageAsync().execute();
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> av) {
        }
    });

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_smscollection, menu);
    return true;
}

private class sendMessageAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pd = ProgressDialog.show(Smscollection.this, null, "Loading...",
                true, true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Message Sending Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        try {
            return doInBg();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        pd.dismiss();
        if (result == null) {
            // request failed!
            // return;
        }
        values = String.valueOf(result).split("<br/>");
        adapter.clear();
        for (String str : values) {
            adapter.add(str);
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}

public String doInBg() {
    String responseRes = null;
    try {
        final String msgURL = "http://freesmsit.tk/msg/messages.php?category="
                + String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString()
                        .replace(" ", "%20"));
        URLConnection connection = new URL(msgURL).openConnection();
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
        InputStream responseStream = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(responseStream));
        response = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(line);
        }
        responseRes = response.toString();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return responseRes;
}
}
```

Comment: How about posting the logcat for the exception itself? That would be more useful.

Comment: @TedHopp i have added the full log cat output

Comment: funny, this should work as ArrayAdapter is supposed to provide an actual List when you pass an array. I would create a new Adapter rather than clearing and adding new items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use an `array` as the data for an `ArrayAdapter` that array will be transformed into a  special `ArrayList`(not the normal one from the platform) which doesn't have implemented the `add` and `remove` methods(you can only modify the items already present in that list). So, when you'll try to add items to the adapter with the method `add` the app will fail with the exception you see.

The solution is to replace the `values` array that you use in the `ArrayAdapter` with a `List`, like an `ArrayList`(the normal one).

```
private ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and then modify the rest of your code to use the list instead of an array.

Comment: Thank you so much... you made my day, or let say "night"!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: what is `items` here? because in my code i dont have anything whose object name is `items`

Comment: Most of this stuff is [here](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1659127).

Comment: @SwiftAppDesign i have successfully created a `listview` using array with static values. but now i want to assign dynamic values by reading the webpage. this is where i am facing the problem

Comment: @SwiftAppDesign please refer my whole code. i think you will get a better idea about what am i trying to do

Answer (score 0):

**You are using on adapter non generic array -  String[]**

any operation on adapter involving generic List interface methods (add, remove, clear) will fail**

```
private String[] values = new String[0];

adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
```

so:

**solution 1:**

- using Arrays.asList([]) in code:

  ```
  adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
      android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, Arrays.asList(values));
  ```

**solution 2:**

- using new array initialization (constructor):

  ```
  List<String> valuesAsArray = newArrayList<String>(values);
  ```

**solution 3:**

- declare your "values variable" as variable implementing List interface

  ```
  List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
  ```